# IIS 7 Can you rewrite a rewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, railo

I am trying to get something like this working with iis 7 microsoft rewrite plugin.

> if user requests...
>   /author/bob/ - show bobs author page
>   if user requests ...
>   /author/bob/rss - show authors rss page by rewriting it to
>   /author/bob/?rss

however i want to to do it in a generic way for urls that end with /rss e.g. for 2 path parts...

```
<rule name="rss 2 dir listing" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/rss$" />       
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}/{R:2}/?rss" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

so the above rule would have to go through to another rewrite rule i.e the one that maps to the author page.

but it looks like this now tries to may to a static directory i.e. the 404 error output is

```
Requested URL   http://site.l:80/author/bob/?rss
Physical Path   C:\Users\Workspace\site.l\author\bob\
```

so its looking for a static  directory but you can see its rewritten in to ?rss and trying the url `http://site.l:80/author/bob/?rss` in the browser works

I am using iis with railo tomcat so it could be a connector issue

Here is the current author rule with the rss incorporated ideally i want to remove adding rss per rule and use generic rules above.

```
<rule name="author item" stopProcessing="false">
<match url="^author/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/(rss)?$" />     
<action type="Rewrite" url="/index.cfm?event=AuthorController.getItem&amp;name={R:1}&amp;{R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're attempting to do, but you need to post both rules, remembering that order is important. (Also is IIS connected to Tomcat or Jetty; using Railo Installer/Helicon/other?)

Comment: I am looking for /rss at the end of an url and then looking to route it to its version without the rss but with rss passed as a query param. Any clearer? I am using standard tomcat railo setup on version 4.05.